# Laravel retrieve model with best match query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller

I have three tables seekers, jobs and skills. a user has many skills and also a job has many skills so i have these relations,

```
class Job extends Model
{
    public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'jobs_skills', 'job_id', 'skill_id');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Seeker extends Model
{
    public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'seekers_skills', 'seeker_id', 'skill_id');
    }
}
```

and

```
class skills extends Model
{
    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Job::class, 'jobs_skills', 'skill_id', 'job_id')->withPivot('level1');
    }

    public function seekers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Seeker::class, 'seekers_skills', 'skill_id', 'seeker_id');

    }
}
```

I wrote this query to get the related jobs to the seekers based on skills

```
public function relatedJobs()
{
    $skills = $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'seekers_skills', 'seeker_id', 'skill_id')->pluck('skill_id');

    $job_ids = DB::table('jobs_skills')->whereIn('skill_id', $skills)->pluck('job_id');

    $jobs = Job::whereIn('id', $job_ids)->with('skills')->get()->sortBy(function ($job) {
        return $job->skills2->groupBy('pivot.job_id')->count();
    });

    return $jobs;
}
```

This function return the related jobs but not sorted with the best matched with the skills of the seeker 
any help ? 
btw I need the return to be an object of Job